# Change element class on ViewChild in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using ViewChild in Angular 2 to isolate an element. I can directly manipulate the styles but I cannot find documentation on if it is possible to change the elements style class.

This is sample code:

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('slideBg') el:ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit {
        // style can be changed
        this.el.nativeElement.style.background = 'red';
        // does not work:
        this.el.nativeElement.class = 'myCSSclass';
    }

    …

}
```

Looking to see if this is possible and how. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems you are looking for `className` property:

```
this.el.nativeElement.className = 'myCSSclass';
```

[Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Comment: It was slightly different for me: `this.el.getNativeElement().className = 'myCSSclass';`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem - wanted to change the CSS of a specific element of the ngFor list so the user receives dopamine by clicking on it with a changing style.

This is a workaround if as me you're not satisfied with ViewChild.
If this can help someone I succeeded like that:

HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let activity of activities">
   // in case the div has the attribute "isTapped" we give it the class "active" with the [ngClass] and its ternary condition
     <div (click)="someFunction(activity)"  [ngClass]="activity.isTapped === true ? 'active' : ''"> 
     </div>
  </div>
```

TS:

```
  someFunction(activity) {
   // this precise div of the ngFor (and not the others) has now the attribute "isTapped" true
   activity.isTapped = true;
  // i put the attribute false after 100ms so the animation will occur again if i retap the div element
   setTimeout(() => { 
    activity.isTapped = false;
   }, 100);
  }
```

CSS:

```
 // whatever div with the class "active" has now these CSS parameters
 // (in this case, changing the background and giving it a quick animation)
 .active {
   background-color: rgba(188, 255, 177, 0.568);
   animation: cardify 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1.28) ;
 }
 @keyframes cardify {
  50% {
    transform: scale(.9);
   }
 }
```